# Extend line to specific point

Tags: qgis, python, line, editing

I have a line layer which is cut at the level of the point layer, 
[image]

I want it to be connected at the nearest point while saving the forme ( just adding the missing part the that line without moving it) as showing in the next picture

[image]

My idea is to calculate the distance between each extremity of the line with the points and take the nearest point then draw a line between them..But the drowing come out bizzarly.

[image][image]
I was wondering ,Is there a simple way of doing this or maybe could anyone help me with the following code?

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import processing
layer = iface.activeLayer()
feat1=layer.selectedFeatures()

for lyrr4 in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
  if lyrr4.name().startswith( 'Boitier_B1'):
     ch = lyrr4
     pr= ch.dataProvider()
chs= ch.getFeatures()
for f in feat1:
 min1=10000.55
 min2=10000.55
 attrs = f.attributes()

 idc = f["ID"]
 x1=f["x1"]
 y1=f["y1"]
 x2=f["x2"]
 y2=f["y2"] 
 print "id_cab"
 print idc
 print "x1"
 print x1
 print "y1"
 print x1
 print"x2"
 print x2
 print "y2"
 print y2
 if  "%.2f" % x1 != "%.4f" %xc and "%.2f" %x2 != "%.4f" %xc:
     point1 = QgsPoint(x1,y1)
     point2 = QgsPoint(x2,y2)
     for ch in chs:
         id = ch["ID"]
         xc= ch["xcoord"]
         yc= ch["ycoord"]
         print "id_ch"
         print id
         print "xc"
         print xc
         print "yc"
         print yc
         pointc = QgsPoint(xc,yc)
         geom = f.geometry()
         distance = QgsDistanceArea()
         m1 = distance.measureLine(pointc, point1)
         m2 = distance.measureLine(pointc, point2)
         print "m1"
         print m1
         print "m2"
         print m2
         fet = QgsFeature()
         if m1<min1:
             min1=m1
             pts=pointc
         if m2<min2:
             min2=m2
             idmin2=id
             pts1=pointc
         print "min1"
         print min1
         print "min2"
         print min2
     if min1<5:
         fet.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([pts, point1]))
         fet.setAttributes(attrs)
         outFeat = QgsFeature()
         pr = layer.dataProvider()
         outGeom  = fet.geometry()
         outGeom = outGeom.combine(geom)
         outFeat.setGeometry(outGeom)
         outFeat.setAttributes(attrs)
         layer.addFeatures(([outFeat]))
         layer.deleteFeature(f.id())

     if min2<5:
         fet.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([pts, point2]))
         fet.setAttributes(attrs)
         outFeat = QgsFeature()
         pr = layer.dataProvider()
         outGeom  = fet.geometry()
         outGeom = outGeom.combine(geom)
         outFeat.setGeometry(outGeom)
         outFeat.setAttributes(attrs)
         layer.addFeatures(([outFeat]))
         layer.deleteFeature(f.id())
```